# The upload file function is not working as per requirement Angular n Flask

Tags: python, angular, web, flask

Have a Query guys, please help me executing it!!
I am not getting the desire result, The upload file function is not working as per requirement.The error block is executing instead of the actual function block.

**main.component.ts:**

```
  uploadFile() {
    console.log('Inside  uploadFile');
    const files: FileList = this.fileInput.nativeElement.files;
    console.log('Inside  uploadFile line 02');
    if (files.length === 0) {
      console.log('Inside  uploadFile 03');
      console.log('no file content here');
      console.log('Inside  uploadFile 04');
      return;
    };
    console.log('Inside  uploadFile 05');

    this.restservice.parseTable(files).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('Inside  uploadFile 06');
      console.log('Data that i am sending: ' + data);
    },  (error) => {
      console.log('Inside  uploadFile 07');
      console.log('No Data Found' + error);
    });
}
```

**Service.ts:**

```
parseTable(files) {
    console.log('Inside parsetable function 01');
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      })
    };
    console.log('Inside parsetable function 02');
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
    console.log('Inside parsetable function 03');
    return this.http.post(this.backendAddress, formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

**App.py:**

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['POST','GET'])
#@cross_origin(["http://localhost:4200"])
@cross_origin(allow_headers=['http://localhost:4200'])
def upload_file():
    print(request.files)
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        print('no file in request')
        return"no file in request"
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        print('no selected file')
        return"no selected file"
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        print("hello")
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        #file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return "Successful"
    print("end")
    return"Bye"
```

**OUTPUT:**

Inside handleFileInput

Inside  uploadFile

Inside  uploadFile line 02

Inside  uploadFile 05

Inside parsetable function 01

Inside parsetable function 02

Inside parsetable function 03

Inside  uploadFile 07

No Data Found[object Object]

Comment: Hi and welcome to community! When posting a question you should show that you really tried to find a solution on your own. Describe what you already tried and what exactly your problems are. Otherwise people will think that you are just trying to spare yourself the debugging process, and that is not what this community is for. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @ElisabethStrunk Yes Mam, i am working on it more than a week, i am not getting the solution of it, i know that people here are honourable and are busy with their routine work, i don't want to bother ay one, but what should i do in such a situation when i am unable to resolve some issues at my own by just googling or watching tutorials, this is the last gateway for me and my problems.
Hope you people will cooperate.

Comment: You can start by creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. This alone could help you identify the bug in your code yourself, and if not then you at least have a question that people will be more likely to answer.

Comment: One general tip: Often the code you write will not behave as expected initially. If you want to be successful in programming, it is very important that you learn to debug your code. There is a ton of material out there on how to debug web applications. Also, it is always a good idea to test small parts of your code as soon as you have written them. If you do that, it is much easier to narrow down the cause of a bug. There is also a ton of material out there on testing (unit tests, integration tests etc.). Just google and have fun reading up on these important and super interesting topics.

Comment: @ElisabethStrunk
Thank you so very much Mam
Mam are you on LinkedIn?

Comment: No problem at all! You can find me [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/elisabeth-strunk/) on LinkedIn - always happy to connect!